How do I not trigger my function in PowerShell when I am calling it from another function?
I have my code here:
Function Send-FileWarnings {    
    $missingfileind = 0
    $filesList = @("file_12.txt", "file_2.txt")
    foreach ($pattern in $filesList) {
        if ($file = Get-ChildItem -Path $LOCAL_LOCATION -Filter $pattern -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){}
         else {
            $missingfileind = 1
            Log-Message "$($pattern): does not exist in $LOCAL_LOCATION"            
        }   
    }    Log-Message "##Send-FileWarnings: [END]"
         if ($missingfileind -eq 1)
         {
         CompleteTask $script:Warning }
         else {} 
         
                  
}

I am calling another function CompleteTask which sends an email every time Send-FileWarnings is run. I can't figure out how to only trigger CompleteTask if there are files missing, if there are no files missing then I don't want to run CompleteTask. Am I missing a {} or is my indentation off?

Flip the logic around - assume you are "missing files" only until you first see an actual file.

Try :
foreach ($pattern in $filesList) {
   $file = Get-ChildItem -Path $LOCAL_LOCATION -Filter $pattern -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue{}
   if ($file.Count -eq 0)
   {
       $missingfileind = 1
       Log-Message "$($pattern): does not exist in $LOCAL_LOCATION"
       break            
   }   
}


where do i add my CompleteTask function here? i want it to be triggered when a file is missing, if no files are missing i don't want to trigger 'CompleteTask'

Like you did before after the foreach loop.

@Forgottenluv When you say "a file is missing", do you mean that you need to find at least 1 file matching every $pattern, or do you just need a file matching 1 of the $pattern's?
